Channel Capacity & Dependency Graph
A single-input-single-output communication channel is to be used repetitively. Denote by $X_i \in \mathcal X$ the input at time $i$ and by $Y_i \in \mathcal Y$ the output at time $i$.
Assume the channel is not memoryless and $Y_i$ depends on some of the previous inputs and/or outputs in a particular way (that is the same through all $i$). For example, $Y_i$ might depend on $X_i$ as well as $X_{i-1}$ through transition probabilities $P_{Y|X,X'}(\cdot|\cdot,\cdot)$ for all $i$ (where $X'$ represents the input at the previous transmission). For another example, $Y_i$ might depend on $X_i$ as well as $Y_{i-1}$ through transition probabilities $P_{Y|X,Y'}(\cdot|\cdot,\cdot)$ for all $i$ (where $Y'$ represents the output after the previous transmission).
We study the input-output relations of $n$ consecutive channel uses. $\{ X_i \}_{i=1}^n$ are the inputs and $\{ Y_i \}_{i=1}^n$ are the corresponding outputs. We represent the dependency relations of these by a graph with $2n$ nodes (one for each $X_i$ and for each $Y_i$), where there is a directed edge whenever there is a dependency. See the examples in the figures below.
Figure 1
Figure 2
Figure 3
Call this graph the dependency graph of the channel.
My question is: Are there works in the literature where channel capacity or other quantities of the channel are studied in connection with the properties of its dependency graph?

Throwing away the actual channel matrix changes the model from a probabilistic to a possibilistic one. Taint analysis could take care of that. Have you checked for sources on that topic?

It is not quite "throwing away the actual channel matrix".
The catch is that the channel is not necessarily memoryless. At transmission $n$, the output $Y_n$ might be depending on $X_n$ as well as other quantities (such as $X_{n-1}$ and/or $Y_{n-1}$).
There is still a transition matrix; it is just larger. Instead of $P_{Y|X}$, we would have transition probabilities for instance of the form $P_{Y|X,X'}$ or $P_{Y|X,Y'}$ (where $X'$ represents the previous output and $Y'$ represents the previous output, if the current output depends on them)
